# How do I create an auto play logo carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

I'm having a trouble creating an **infinite auto play logo carousel**. I want to create the carousel in a React project.
I think there are 2 approaches for creating it. One using *JavaScript*. Second using *CSS* only.
How do I achieve this?

**Note:** I'm using styled components. Besides, the SVG which is the logo contain a lot of data as an example I put it empty.

```
   const Container = styled.div`` 
   
   const Slider = styled.div`
           display: flex;
           flex-wrap: nowrap;
          
           div{
              width: 300px;
              height: 200px;
              background: #fff;
              overflow: hidden;
              padding: 15px 15px;
              margin: 0px 12px;
    

             svg{
               max-height: 100%;
               width: 100%;
             }
           }

 const Clients = () => {
        return (
           <Container>
             <Slider>
               <div><svg></svg></div> 
               <div><svg></svg></div> 
               <div><svg></svg></div> 
               <div><svg></svg></div> 
               <div><svg></svg></div> 
               <div><svg></svg></div> 
               <div><svg></svg></div> 
            </Slider>
          </Container>
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be using JavaScript. One way this could be done is by first creating a collection of your images, for example an array of objects containing image links.

```
[
{"image": "url"},
{"image": "url"}
]
```

Then import this data into your component, and use map to iterate through it and an interval to change the slide every x seconds. [Here's](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-hooks-slider-how-to-build-an-image-slider-with-autoplay-part-2-c94deaf763c4) a guide on it if you need more help.

Also, you should probably add another ` before the `const Clients` to end the styled div.